# COUNTIF multiple criteria in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I'm trying to make a count function in Google Sheets that takes multiple arguments from different sheets. However, I can't really get it to work. The COUNTIFs are referring to two different columns within the same Google spreadsheet. They work separately but I don't know how to combine them. I've tried with COUNTIFS and looked at previous posts but haven't had any success with it. I'd appreciate any answer very much.

```
=COUNTIF('Group 3 (7-9)'!$D$2:$D$100;7)+ COUNTIF('Group 3 (7-9)'!$G$2:$G$100;"Woman")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
=COUNTIFS('Group 3 (7-9)'!$D$2:$D$100; 7 ; 'Group 3 (7-9)'!$G$2:$G$100; "Woman")
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the need

`COUNTIFS` condition columns are parallel to the usage of the operator `AND` where adding `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` are parallel to the usage of the operator `OR`

Comment: The thing is, I want the first part of the formula is counting if the participants for my experiment is in a specific order and the second part is counting whether they're men or women. Does that make sense?

Comment: not really, nooo   :) can yoy define your question in general?